# Precise Strike with thrown weapon

Tags: pathfinder-2e, swashbuckler

[Swashbucklers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=15) have limitation on using Precise Strike:

> When you have panache and **you Strike with an agile or finesse melee weapon** or agile or finesse unarmed attack, you deal 2 additional precision damage

A [Combat Grapnel](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=139) for example is a melee weapon with both the *Thrown* and *Finesse* properties. I know such distinctions<sup>1</sup> were intentional in Dnd-4e, but what is the case in Pathfinder 2e?
Can I use Precise Strike with a thrown Combat Grapnel?

---

1. Attack with a melee weapon ≠ melee attack with a weapon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### When thrown, the weapon is ranged.

From the [Thrown](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=195) trait:

> You can throw this weapon as a ranged attack, and it is a ranged weapon when thrown.

When you Strike with a thrown weapon, you choose whether it will act as a melee weapon (by attacking with it normally) or a ranged one (by throwing it). In this case, Precise Strike would grant additional precision damage on melee attacks with the Combat Grapnel, but not its thrown attacks (though you could use [Flying Blade](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1515) to get around this restriction within the first range increment).

As far as I'm aware, Pathfinder 2e lacks the distinction like the one mentioned in 4e D&D. Some actions that require melee weapons will use language like the Swashbuckler, ex. "a Strike with a melee weapon or unarmed attack," while others (like the Magus's [Spellstrike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=755)) specify you must "make a melee Strike with a weapon or unarmed attack." These appear to be interchangeable.

In a similar case, the cantrip [Produce Flame](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=236) has a melee and ranged use. You select whether the cantrip will act as a melee or ranged spell attack when you cast it.